# Check if a String is a Keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any possible way (like a method from another class) where one would be able to check if a text such as `Shift + Ctrl + D` is a Keyboard shortcut?

I have a couple of Keyboard shortcuts saved in a textfile. Now I want to cycle through each line and make sure that the string is indeed a shortcut, and not just some gibberish text like `hello world`.

Previously I used the `ConvertToString` method from the `KeyConverter` class to convert `e.KeyValue` to a string, but it doesn't seem like they have a method to reverse it.

Comment: I think you'll need to hard-code this e.g. `if (myString == "Shift + Ctrl + D") { //Do some stuff }`

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific as to what constitutes a keyboard shortcut, and the exact format that such a shortcut will always be in.

Comment: Is `Shift + A` a shortcut? Is `abc + def + xyz` a shortcut?

Comment: The basic task of my application is to map a text output to Keyboard shortcut the user has defined. Shortcuts can be all types of combinations (`A`,`Shift + A`,`Ctrl + F1`, `Shift + Alt + F12`etc).

All I need now is to make sure the user didn't modify the file. I need to make sure the software doesn't crash when the shortcut is read, because it may not be a shortcut at all..

Comment: @Dean so it looks like you either: a) need to compile a list of all the possible shortcut keys, and then just look at each shortcut and compare it to that list by doing `string.Split` by " + " or b) save a checksum/hash when you write the file in the first place that can then be recalculated to ensure that the file wasn't changed. A determined person could still change the hash, but maybe this is suitable?

Comment: Guess there isn't any workaround on this other than creating a list of all keyboard keys and comparing them with the string.. Why does it always have to be the hard way? :<

Comment: I've also just seen that the `KeyConverter` class has a [`ConvertFromString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.convertfromstring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_ComponentModel_TypeConverter_ConvertFromString_System_String_) method, could this be of any use?

Comment: @CallumWatkins That's it! I was sure I have already tried that function, but it didn't work back then.

After trying again, all good. Thank you very much. I would appreciate if you post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyConverter` class has a [`ConvertFromString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.convertfromstring#System_ComponentModel_TypeConverter_ConvertFromString_System_String_) function which you can use to reverse the conversion.

It should throw a `NotSupportedException` if the string is invalid.